# DioError Http Status Error 405 when Using Dio.delete

Tags: flutter, api, http, request, dio

I am using `Dio` library and everything is ok with `Get` and `Post` but when I use `Delete` it shows the 405 error from application only.

When I try it on swagger it works fine?

The head of `BaseOptions` for entire application requests:

```
headers: {
'Accept': 'application/json'
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
```

The request is:

```
dio.delete(path, data: json.encode(data));
```

The response should be:

```
{success: true, data: true}
```

Comment: Do you find solution? In my example I get error 400 when call api url from postman everything is ok

Comment: I found this, when using api on local iis DELETE and PUT methods gives me the error but when I uploaded it to the server every thing work successfuly!.